# While Loop stuck indefinitely using string comparison condition - Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to check the output from an http call, if the variable matches the a string I want to terminate the loop. Unfortunately, that is not happening in my case it is not terminating the loop. Here is my code :

```
        while [[ "$BUILD_STATUS" != "SUCCESS" ]];
        do

            http_response_1=$(curl -s -o response_1.json -w "%{http_code}" ${CREATE_BUILD_URL}/${BUILD_CODE}/progress -H 'Authorization: Token' -H 'Content-Type:application/json')
            BUILD_PERCENTAGE=$(jq -r .percentage response_1.json)
            BUILD_STATUS=$(jq .buildStatus response_1.json)
            echo "$BUILD_STATUS"

            rm response_1.json
            echo "File Removed"
            sleep 10
        done
```

Comment: What does the `echo "$BUILD_STATUS"` output? Try to replacing it with `echo "[$BUILD_STATUS]"` to check for trailing whitespace, maybe even pipe the output to a hexdump.

Comment: There is no trailing whitespace.

Comment: Use `jq -r` to get a raw string rather than a JSON string: `BUILD_STATUS=$(jq -r .buildStatus response_1.json)`. Also I'd recommend you run `jq` only once and read both answers.

Comment: Regarding Léa Gris's comment, do you see `SUCCESS` as the output, or `"SUCCESS"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly have `jq` make the string comparison and return a status accordingly:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

while
  build_percentage="$(
    curl \
      --silent \
      --write-out "%{http_code}" \
      --header 'Authorization: Token' \
      --header 'Content-Type:application/json' \
      --url "${CREATE_BUILD_URL}/${BUILD_CODE}/progress"  |
    jq \
      --exit-status \
      --raw-output \
'.percentage,
if .buildStatus != "SUCCESS"
  then empty
  else halt_error(1)
end
' 2>/dev/null
  )"
do
  printf 'Build percentage: %d%%\n' "$build_percentage"
  sleep 10
done

printf 'Build percentage: %d%%\nStatus: SUCCESS!\n' "$build_percentage"
```